# Animation doesn't get executed while rotating closing tableview expanded section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I've built an expandable Tableview and I want an arrow which points to the left when the cell is not expanded and down if the cell is expanded.

The first animation (To point the arrow down) Works like a charm. When trying to rotate back (while closing the expanded Cell), it just jumps back to normal without any animation.
In my cellForRow I do this:

```
cell.image1.rotate(item.opened ? -.pi/2 : 0, duration: 0.4)
```

I have an extension for it:

```
extension UIView {
    func rotate(_ toValue: CGFloat, duration: CFTimeInterval) {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        animation.toValue = toValue
        animation.duration = duration
        animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards
        self.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

This one works like a charm outside of the tableview. But inside the Tableview it always goes back to normal without the animation.
Any idea where this comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer. 
It jumped back (without any animation) because of how my rotate function was executed. Doing the animation when inputting 0 didn't work, because the image was set in the cell when it reloaded. So there was nothing to animate. Now I just set the picture and animate it afterwards.

```
if item.opened{
            cell.image1.image = UIImage(named: "back")
            cell.image1.rotate(-.pi/2, duration: 0.3)
} else {
            cell.image1.image = UIImage(named: "down")
            cell.image1.rotate(.pi/2, duration: 0.3)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call rotation in the `action` method instead of `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Try the code below.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.rotateArrow()
}
```

In CustomTableViewCell

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var arrowImageView: UIImageView!

    var isOpened = false

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func rotateArrow() {

        isOpened = !isOpened
        arrowImageView.rotate(isOpened ? -.pi/2 : 0, duration: 0.4)
    }
}
```

Comment: Same result as before.
I think it has something to do with how I hide the extended Cell.
      let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
                tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .none)